# A book for relativistic quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, resource-recommendations

What is the best book to learn relativistic quantum mechanics at first time? I would like a book that also talk about the representations of the Lorentz group and the Poincaré group.

Comment: Relativistic quantum mechanics, most known as quantum field theory :p

Answer (score 1):

Note that it is inevitable to go to quantum field theory, that is, many-particle theory, if you want relativistic extension.
A book giving the complete answer to what you asked is Weinberg, vol. 1. However an accessible book would be Peskin and Schroeder. A particle theory book like Halzen and Martin would be also a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

Relativistic extension of quantum mechanics will extend naturally into quantum field theory and on a beginner level, my suggestions would be to follow the book by Lewis H. Ryder and Mark Srednicki. A more theoretical approach can be found in the book named "Quantum Field Theory in a nutshell" by Anthony Zee. QFT books of Peskin and Schroeder, and Weinberg Volume 1 are the ultimate books to go to in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Previous posts highlighted that it proved to be difficult to design a relativistic quantum theory that is not a quantum field theory. As a reference to why that is the case, maybe the [book by Strocchi](https://www.amazon.de/Introduction-Non-Perturbative-Foundations-International-Monographs/dp/0199671575) is helpful. It is mostly about quantum field theory, but the first chapter deals with attempts to formulate relativistic wave equations that have a probabilistic interpretation.